# hack: Modifying :before in inline css

Tags: html, css

I have in an ASP.NET (razor) page a "dynamic style" (don't ask why, is just like this)

```
<div class="myClass" style="background-image: url('@myUrl');">
```

everything works like a charm. But it apprers that now I need to put the url in the ".myClass:before" (to crop the background-image height via `myClass:before{height:100px; position: absolute; background-image:url('@myUrl'); z-index:-1;}`).

This modification can be only done in CSS, but `@myUrl` is a dynamic value... and we have no dynamic CSS yet... What to do as a quickfix?

Comment: You can't, mainly because the :before element isn't a real element to manipulate?

Comment: AFAIK nothing. CSS can't detect an inline style and extend it to something in stylesheet.

Comment: I understand, but searching for a hack...

Comment: Add a `<style>` element, write it in plain old CSS and inject the variable?

Comment: partial view, has no acces to head element... but via jquery maybe...

Comment: Data attribute perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `inherit` keyword for the `background-image` of the `:before` pseudoelement, so it will inherit automatically the background defined for the `div`.

Also set a `background-size: 0 0` to the div so the image won't be visibile twice.

```
div {
   background-size: 0 0;
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background-image: inherit; 
  background-size: <your size here>;
  position: absolute;
  ...
}
```

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqbKde

Comment: this really can be a solution (if the div background does not use a self image)